# Kohana 3.3 ORM Validation - unique value not working when value is empty

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-3.3

In a Model_Page class, extending the Kohana ORM class, I have this rules definition :

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        'url' => array(
            array('Model_Page::unique_url', array($this)),
        ),
    );
}
```

To simplify here, I will just return false from this function, so it should never validate when I try to save/update a page :

```
public static function unique_url($page) {
  return false;
}
```

This works as expected, *if* the value for url is *not NULL* or *not an empty string*.

But if I already have a page with an empty url, and that I try to add a new page with an empty url, the unique_url function is ignored, even when forcing a return false.

This could be a bug, but maybe I missed something...? In the Kohana docs, for the unique example, they use a username as an example, but the username also has a not_empty rule, which does not apply here.

Any help/suggestion appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the rule is applied once you set the value, not when you're saving it.

I had a similar issue - the filter wasn't working if I didn't assign any value to the field. I've written my own save method:

```
public function save(Validation $validation = NULL)
{
    if (!$this->loaded())
    {
        $this->ordering = 0;
    }

    return parent::save($validation);
}
```

this way the ordering would always be assigned for newly created objects and my filter would work.

And that's how I built another model. It's a company model that has a unique company name. Rules for the field are defined like this:

```
'name' => array(
    array('not_empty'),
    array('max_length', array(':value', 255)),
    array(array($this, 'unique_name'))
)
```

And I have a method:

```
public function unique_name($value)
{
    $exists = (bool) DB::select(array(DB::expr('COUNT(*)'), 'total_count'))
        ->from($this->_table_name)
        ->where('name', '=', $value)
        ->where($this->_primary_key, '!=', $this->pk())
        ->execute($this->_db)
        ->get('total_count');

    return !$exists;
}
```

It basically checks if there are any other companies with the same name as the current one. Maybe this will give you the idea of what could be wrong with your solution.

Comment: What do you mean? I do set the value to an empty string, so the validation should fire anyway no..?

Comment: Try the die('XXX') in your method. Then different scenarios - create new page and save it, crate new page, assign value and save, load existing without the value and save again, load existing, set value and save etc. You'll get to it

Comment: I did all that. Also your save function would not work for me, I am not necessary doing a save, but also updates, so my url value cannot be set by default like you did, it is set by the values() function.

Comment: I tried a similar function than your save() function, except I wrote $this->url = ''. With an empty string, the validation does not fire the error, problem remains.

Comment: Check my update - it's a working example from my other Kohana based project. Of course my case also has not_empty rule...

Comment: I mentioned that if you have  an array('not_empty') rule, it will work. The problem comes from here. Try to remove you not_empty rule, and your filter will not fire. This is my problem, I must allow url to be empty.

Comment: You're right. If there's no not_empty rule and I don't assign anything - the unique method doesn't get called