# Using this in an array is causing unexpected T_Variable

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, orm, kohana

I'm using Kohana 3.3 and trying to write a custom validation rule to ensure that users username and e-mail address are unique. I'm following the instructions from an [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172306/kohana-3-3-orm-validation-unique-value-not-working-when-value-is-empty), and the [Kohana documentation here](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/validation#external-validation), but whenever I try to add in `array(array($this, 'unique_email'))` I get `syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')'`.

If I put `array(array('Model_User', 'unique_email'))` I don't get any errors, but why would using `$this` cause an error? For completeness I've posted the full class below.

```
class Model_User extends ORM {


    protected $_rules = array(
        'email'     => array(
            array(array($this, 'unique_email')),
        )
    );

    public function unique_email()
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: @kingkero The documentation only has the first array. I don't understand it enough to know what I need to do.

Comment: That wasn't the problem but a mistake on my part. See jszobody's answer for the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When declaring class properties, you can only use constant values.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

So you can't use `$this` when first declaring your class property.

You *can* use `$this` in the constructor. So you could do something like this:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->_rules['email'] = array(
        array(array($this, 'unique_email'))
    );
}
```

**Edit**: kingkero points out in the comments that Kohana provides you with a [rules()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Model_Auth_User#rules) method, which you should probably use instead of the constructor.

Comment: True. Kohana solves this by adding these rules in the [`rules()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Model_Auth_User#rules) method. I'm not sure overwriting the constructor is such a good idea as at least you'd need to call sth like `parent::__construct()` (no idea if that works but the point should be clear)

Comment: @kingkero Yeah I was primarily explaining the core PHP issue here, and the generally recommended constructor answer. Using rules() though is clearly the way to go for this specific Kohana situation.